# change default firewall policies to DENY using firewalld-cmd

Tags: centos, rhel, firewalld

According to `CIS CentOS Linux 7 Benchmark` document for Centos7, the recommendation:

```
3.5.3.2.1 Ensure default deny firewall policy
```

says to set all policies to DROP:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

However, whenever I run "`firewall-cmd --reload`" above policies are set back to `ACCEPT`

What is the correlation here between `iptables` and `firewalld` and how to change mentioned `iptables` policies to `DROP` using `"firewall-cmd"` so the change is permanent and CIS benchmark stops complaining about it?

There is no iptables service on `Centos` by default and don't want to have as there is "native" Firewalld instead as in whole "Redhat" OS family.

```
# systemctl status iptables
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

When I set in Firewalld default zone to "DROP", the iptables policies are still "ACCEPT" and CIS is complaining about it.

Answer (score 2):

First `iptables` is a  tool for network packets filtering, Instead there is a daemon `iptables-services` that can be used along with iptables but does not comes with Centos 7 (it needs to be installed).

`Firewalld` is a service that is used to handle `iptables` configuration in another way (zones, services, rich rules etc.) to manipulate packets on the kernel level (`netfilter`).

Setting `iptables` rules will not reflect to `firewalld` but the inverse will be true.

I think you have some `firewalld` policies that are **conflicting** with your iptables 'DROP' rules; that's what make the rules disappearing when executing `firewall-cmd --reload` because normally reload command will only affect those rules managed by firewalld.

Check this and find out which rules are conflicting :

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

In the meantime you will be able to change the default iptables chains via  `firewall-cmd` by :

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT  0 -j REJECT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -j REJECT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -j REJECT
firewall-cmd --reload
```

And check the configuration via :

```
iptables -L 
firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
```

Comment: I can't find any conflict. Could you provide a firewall-cmd command which would set the policies DENY on iptabls?

Comment: Check my edit :)